# *** [Makefile:666: all-recursive] Error 1

Tags: error-handling, makefile, compiler-errors

Aoa,
Hello all,

I am compiling GPG4win from source code, but at make command following error occurs:

```
**Output written on gpg4win-compendium-de.pdf (155 pages, 3042581 bytes).
Transcript written on gpg4win-compendium-de.log.
/usr/bin/texi2dvi: pdflatex exited with bad status, quitting.
make[4]: *** [Makefile:1117: gpg4win-compendium-de.pdf] Error 1
make[4]: Leaving directory '/home/mmm/Downloads/gpg4win-3.1.16/doc/manual'
make[3]: *** [Makefile:811: all] Error 2
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/mmm/Downloads/gpg4win-3.1.16/doc/manual'
make[2]: *** [Makefile:666: all-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/mmm/Downloads/gpg4win-3.1.16/doc'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:730: all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/mmm/Downloads/gpg4win-3.1.16'
make: *** [Makefile:671: all] Error 2**
```

Comment: Are there more errors before that?  It looks like these messages are just telling you that something failed earlier, but not saying _what_ failed.  They aren't sufficient for us to be able to help you.  You should always start looking at errors by investigating the _first_ errors listed, not the last errors listed.

Comment: I have checked that no errors occur before that. And my system is ubuntu 20

Comment: Well, either there's no error and `pdflatex` is not well behaved and is exiting with a failure exit code even when nothing went wrong, or there's some error that is happening.  You could try looking in the log file mentioned above to see if there are any issues.  Else, you will need to talk to people who know about texi2dvi and pdflatex: you should reset the question tags to attract those people.  There's nothing wrong (as far as we can see) with your makefile and you're not using a compiler at all, so tags like `makefile` and `compiler-errors` aren't appropriate.